# Passing env variables in json file

Tags: json

I have a simple JSON file where I need to pass the value from my env variables. How can this be done?

sample.json

```
{
"report": {
    "ds": "Test",
    "public": process.env.PUBLIC_VALUE
  }
}
```

The PUBLIC_VALUE env variable needs to be read in this JSON file and either TRUE or FALSE has to be set to public attribute.

Comment: JSON is data structure and can not process values (same as e.g. XML or CSV). You need some kind of JSON processor. But that will be language dependant

Comment: This is an XY problem. *why* do you need this? Ask that question.

Comment: @Evert Basically this property is used in Loopback framework to show or hide a Data object. And we need to handle it dynamically

Comment: @SouravMehra I suppose this is some kind of start-up configuration file? Your options are basically as follows: Write code to change this setting when your application boots, or *create* the JSON file dynamically right before the application starts. The former is probably a bit more robust. If this is not helpful enough I would recommend you try to ask a new question on stackoverflow asking how you solve your loopback-specific problem.